# How to Incorporate an Array Into Model Object With Mantle?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, github-mantle

I have a JSON object like so:

```
{
   "name": "Brendan",
   "images": ["some.url.to.image1",
             "some.url.to.image2",
             "some.url.to.image3"]
}
```

My class is as follows:

```
@interface MyModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *images;

@end

@implementation MYModel

+ (NSDictionary*)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
             @"name" : @"name",
             @"images" : @"images"
             };
}

@end
```

I can verify that MYModel object has `name` properly set, but `images` is set to `null`. How can I populate an array of strings with Mantle?

Comment: This ends up working as is. I ended up making the mistake of using the incorrect case of the JSONKey for `images` in my version of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Apparently `mtl_externalRepresentationArrayTransformerWithModelClass:` is deprecated. This might work:

```
[MTLJSONAdapter arrayTransformerWithModelClass:[NSString class]];
```

---

You need to specify value transformer for key `images` as Array value transformer. You can do this with class method (on your `MyModel` class) with correct name. Something like this might work. I have not tested the code.

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)imagesTransformer
{
    return [NSValueTransformer mtl_externalRepresentationArrayTransformerWithModelClass:[NSString class]];
}
```

Comment: The code you provided doesn't compile due to `mtl_externalRepresentationArrayTransformerWithModelClass` not being found. I tried this `return [MTLJSONAdapter arrayTransformerWithModelClass:[NSString class]];` and the app merely crashes on that line. The console spits out: `*** Assertion failure in +[MTLJSONAdapter dictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:], /Users/dcaunt/Projects/Mantle/Mantle/MTLJSONAdapter.m:476`.